# Cross Validation(k-fold) for multiple regression using glm.fit

Tags: r, cross-validation

I am trying to do k-fold CV in R using a dataset containing 58 rows. I saw an example of finding predicted error for polynomial of the predictor online [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/cross-validation-estimating-prediction-error/).  So I modified the code to suit my need by taking set.seed as initialization in my code.

```
cv.error.10 = rep(0,10)
for (i in 1:10){
set.seed(i)
train = sample(58,29)
glm.fit = glm(HtVol~.,data = Set1, subset = train)
cv.error.10[i] = cv.glm(Set1, glm.fit, K=10)$delta[1]
}
cv.error.10
```

But when i see the results for cv.error.10 , I see a list of NA. I am not sure what error I have made in the process. can anyone guide me on it?
My goal is to divide my dataset into 50-50 training-testing datasets and perform 10-fold CV and estimate RMSE,MAE and Symmetric
Median Absolute Percentage Error (sMdAPE)
Thanks.